# Replace Fragments

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android, android-gui

I have the following XML for my Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <br.com.digitalpages.shelves.view.TopBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60px" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_categories"
            android:layout_width="240px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="br.com.digitalpages.shelves.fragment.TreeCategoryFragment" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_library"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:name="br.com.digitalpages.shelves.fragment.LibraryFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="br.com.digitalpages.shelves.fragment.BottomBarFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In a click on the Bottom_Bar I need to replace fragment_categories and fragment_library by another Fragment that span the space of the old fragments.

How can I do that?

I tried:

```
        FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.remove(categoryExplorerFragment);
        trans.remove(libraryFragment);
        trans.add(R.id.fragment_container, new LibraryFragment());
        trans.commit();
```

But when I click, only the libraryFragment disappears and nothing more happens.

Answer (score 0):

use the replace method instead;

```
FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new LibraryFragment()); 
trans.commit();
```

Comment: Same result PS: fragment_container is the LinearLayout that has two fragments that should be replaced by one